# Fibonacci - Why is this giving me the incorrect calculation?

Tags: java, math, fibonacci

The problem is...

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

I have made a code that should do this, pasted below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Setting up the variables. sumF3 will be printed at the end.
        int sumF1 = 1;
        int sumF2 = 2;
        int sumF3 = 0;
        // If loops to cancel out the odd numbers, but let them be added to sumF2 etc anyway.
        while(4000000 > sumF1) {
            if (sumF1 % 2 == 0) {
                sumF3 += sumF1;
            }
            if (sumF2 % 2 == 0) {
                sumF3 += sumF2;
            }
            // Normal fibonacci sequence.
            sumF1 += sumF1 + sumF2;
            sumF2 += sumF1 + sumF2;
        }
        System.out.println(sumF3);
    }
}
```

I start by filtering out the odd numbers with two if loops, and then add it to sumF3. It will keep on doing this adding to sumF3 till it hits under 4 million. When the while loop stops, it is supposed to print out '4613732', however it prints off something different (4194302). I feel like there's a logic flaw here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expressions in your fibonacci sequence are incorrect. You are doing the following:

```
// Normal fibonacci sequence.
        sumF1 += sumF1 + sumF2;
        sumF2 += sumF1 + sumF2;
```

Which is essentially doing this:

`sumF1 = sumF1+sumF1+sumF2, sumF2 = sumF2+sumF1+sumF2.`

If you change the expression to the following, you should get the correct answer:

```
// Normal fibonacci sequence.
        sumF1 += sumF2;
        sumF2 += sumF1;
```

The += operator adds the value of an expression to the value of a variable and assigns the result to the variable. You are adding an additional variable in the mix which throws off your result.

Answer (score 5):

You actually only made a small mistake. The lines

```
sumF1 += sumF1 + sumF2;
sumF2 += sumF1 + sumF2;
```

Should be

```
sumF1 = sumF1 + sumF2;
sumF2 = sumF1 + sumF2;
```

Note the `=` instead of the `+=`.